# Interactive sorting based on totals

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

I have the following report that looks like this in design mode:

[image]

The field I'd like to sort on is the `<<Expr>>` field highlighted in yellow `TOTAL` row. That expression reads like this:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox12.Value+ReportItems!Price3.Value
```

When previewed, the report looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to be able to sort the `TOTAL` row for all of the report. My desired result would have the group with the $38.52 total first, $0.92 total second, and so on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the Sorting on the Row Group for Patient Name.  Sort expressions cannot reference ReportItems so I would get the Expressions inside those Report Items references and copy them into the Sort Expression.

And that is seriously the worst color scheme I have ever seen in 30+ years in IT ... it literally makes my eyes water.

Comment: I'm glad you feel so strongly about my color scheme that you had to mention it twice! lol

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when putting the expression from `Textbox12` and `Price3`: http://i.imgur.com/cXfxfMn.png, with these details checked: http://i.imgur.com/deYWtWL.png, it still doesn't sort: http://i.imgur.com/gvFHCRk.png

Comment: Possibly some issue with your Function?  I would debug by pulling out the pieces of that expression into text boxes and adding them to a group row.